# jQuery masked input - format date as m/d/yyyy or m/dd/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy or mm/d/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, formatting

I want to use the jQuery masked input plugin found here http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ to format the date.

I am pulling data from a database to populate the date field when the page loads.  The user will then be able to change the date if it is incorrect.

I want people to be able to enter just one number for the month and day instead of having to enter a 0 before a single-digit number.  I want them to be able to type 6/13/2010 instead of 06/13/2010.  The data from the database might not have 0's in front, though.

I know that anything listed after a ? is optional, but I want characters at the beginning or middle to be optional.

Thanks!

Comment: *The data from the database might not have 0's in front, though.* Thus.. they're stored as varchar instead of as date?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar requirement recently, and the only thing I could find that didn't require me to do a lot of work on tweaking the plugin was to use [this modified date masking plugin that is based on the one you mentioned](http://archive.conductiva.com/en/blog/post/76/Improvement-in-the-Masked-Input-Plugin-for-jQuery). It seems to be doing the job so far.

If you want to test it out, [head to this page](http://archive.conductiva.com/files/demos/maskedin/index.html).

The basic implementation we've used with this modified date masker is as follows:

```
$('#yourInputBoxHere').mask("99/99/9999", {placeholder: 'MM/DD/YYYY' });
```

I haven't tried it with single digits for dates, but if I were to do it, I'd just change the above expression to this:

```
$('#yourInputBoxHere').mask("9/9/9999", {placeholder: 'M/D/YYYY' });
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This just adds a placeholder, And entering the value 99/99/9999 is accepted. Can we set some rules to accept proper date format. `Eg MM should never exceed 12`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is:
It's **not possible** without tweaking the plugin.

But, your users will thank you a lot if you use the [jquery ui datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

It's usage is as simple as:

```
$("#texbox1").datepicker();
```

It will show a nice calendar when the inputbox recieves focus.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: My users will be entering a birth date and marriage date.  Is there a date picker that will allow them to easily select a year that is far from the current date?

Comment: As long as we're talking about what users like make sure you indicate on your page that the format is month-day-year, because Australia, England and most of Europe use day-month-year by default.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this addresses your problem but I found this on https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask:

```
$('#yourInputBoxHere').datepicker().inputmask("date", { placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy", yearrange: { minyear: 1700 } });
```

This will fill in a '0' at the month beginning if you start with a number greater than '1' and for the day if the number is greater than 3, '0' is automatically placed in front.

The `yearrange` can also specify `maxyear`, if you need that criteria.

You can leave out the `.datepicker()` if you don't want the jquery calendar.

Hope this helps!