# Accept one digit date/month in date mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask, maskedinput

There is an input tag which has data mask applied to it.

```
  <input id="newstartdate" data-mask="99/99/9999" type="text" style="width: 100px;" placeholder="(dd/mm/yyy)" required>
```

This allows data to be entered like 02/12/2014 or 13/05/2014. but it does not accept 1/1/2013 or 13/5/2014. Please help!!!

Comment: Check your mask library documentation. There could be a symbol for optional like **9?9/9?9/9999** - this should be described in the documentation of the library

Comment: once check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888730/jquery-masked-input-format-date-as-m-d-yyyy-or-m-dd-yyyy-or-mm-dd-yyyy-or-mm-d?rq=1)

Comment: I tried this 9?9/9?9/9999 it is not accepting

Answer (score 1):

According to the [jQuery Mask documentation](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/docs.html#basic-usage), optional characters can be specified like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#newstartdate").mask('Z9/Z9/9999', {
    translation: {
      'Z': {
        pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input id="newstartdate" type="text" style="width: 100px;" required>
```