# Inputmask jquery not allowing mm/dd/yy format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

I am using Jquery Inputmask to validate date entered by users in a textbox. My requirement is to enter the date in ***mm/dd/yy*** format but Inputmask only allows ***mm/dd/yyyy*** format. Can anyone tell me if there's a workaround to achieve the same result with ***mm/dd/yy*** format.

Edit: The question is showing as possible duplicate but my requirement is to accept date in mm/dd/yy format specifically.

```js
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
   constrainInput:"true",
   dateFormat:"mm/dd/yy"
});


var maskConfig = {
      leapday: "29-02-",
      separator: "/",
      showMaskOnHover: false,
      showMaskOnFocus: false,
      placeholder: "00/00/0000"
}

$('#datepicker1').inputmask('mm/dd/yyyy',maskConfig);
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">

<input type="text" id="datepicker1"/>
```

Comment: Please check this URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888730/jquery-masked-input-format-date-as-m-d-yyyy-or-m-dd-yyyy-or-mm-dd-yyyy-or-mm-d?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery masked input - format date as m/d/yyyy or m/dd/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy or mm/d/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888730/jquery-masked-input-format-date-as-m-d-yyyy-or-m-dd-yyyy-or-mm-dd-yyyy-or-mm-d)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $date = $('.datepicker1');

$date.datepicker({
    format: 'dd/M/yyyy',
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/master/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>



    <input type="text" class="datepicker1"/>
```

Comment: its almost same as my code except you have set maskConfig paramters to true and it still accepts value in mm/dd/yyyy format. My requirement is mm/dd/yy, for example: 12/23/18 for 23rd December 2018

Comment: @subhrendu please check https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ .It may fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(".datepicker1").datepicker({
       constrainInput:"true",
       format:"mm/dd/yy"
    });


    var maskConfig = {
          leapday: "29-02-",
          separator: "/",
          showMaskOnHover: true,
          showMaskOnFocus: true,
          placeholder: "00/00/00"
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>


    <input type="text" class="datepicker1" data-date-format='mm/dd/yy' readonly=""/>
```

Comment: What you are getting?

Comment: While typing I am able to enter each and every number, that is not the requirement

Comment: I think you are not getting my problem, user wants both functionality, 1) Select date from datepicker, 2)Manually enter the date via keyboard but it should not allow user to type invalid date